# How to find data between range of time using grep?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am a new bash script student. I am learning about grep! I have a file that contains information about computer or activity. I am trying to use grep command to find information about my computer during a specific time range. I have tried following commands, but some work and some don't:

```
grep -E "Jan 09 22:00:00 && Jan 09 22:05:00" /etc/active #doesn't work
grep -E "Jan 09 22:00:00" && "Jan 09 22:05:00" /etc/active #doesn't work
```

Then I tried pipe

```
grep -E "Jan 09 22:00:00" | grep -E "Jan 09 22:05:00" /etc/active #doesn't work
```

If I try `grep -E "Jan 09 22:00" /etc/active` this work, but it is only one time. I want between two different times

I know there is a command `awk`, but we haven't started with awk!

Comment: try `grep -E 'Jan 09 22:(0[0-4]:|05:00)' /etc/active`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for simply doesn't work too good with grep. You see, grep is about matching text against **patterns**.

grep has no understanding of "dates"; or the semantics of dates. grep doesn't understand that "Jan 09 22:00:00" denotes a point in time; and that you are looking for the entries up to the next 5 minutes.

The only thing that you can do: use a **pattern** that matches that input.

For example: the pattern

```
 Jan 09 22:0.:..
```

should match any timestamp from 22.00.00 to 22.09.59

In other words: you can study how to create more sophisticated patterns (see [here](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html) for some ideas); and then try to find patterns that match exactly what you need. But please understand that this might be hard, depending on your requirements.

Coming back to my intial point: grep is a tool to do "stupid" text matching. You are looking for something that works on a "higher level of abstraction".

EDIT: I actually really told you what you need to know, but maybe you need an example. So I cretead a file forgrep and put this in

```
Jan 09 22:00:00 zero
Jan 09 22:01:00 one
Jan 09 22:02:00 two
Jan 09 22:03:00 three
```

See what is possible using different regular expressions:

```
grep -E "Jan 09 22:01:00" forgrep 
Jan 09 22:01:00 one
```

The above matches the **exact** string provided, but

```
grep -E "Jan 09 22:0.:00" forgrep 
Jan 09 22:00:00 zero
Jan 09 22:01:00 one
Jan 09 22:02:00 two
Jan 09 22:03:00 three
```

simply matches *any* number there (because of the **.**)

```
grep -E "Jan 09 22:0[12]:00" forgrep 
Jan 09 22:01:00 one
Jan 09 22:02:00 two
```

matches numbers 1 and 2 in that place!

It doesn't get "better than that". You simply have **study** the link I provided to you and start making experiments.

As you can see: you can use patterns to

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. As I said I know other ways like the `awk` command, but my professor said you can't simply use `awk` like `grep` in a bash script and we haven't started chapter on this yet. I can get `grep -E "Jan 09 06" /etc/ative` to work, but as soon as I said minutes to hours like this `grep -E "Jan 09 06:10" /etc/active` it does not show any result! I tried `egrep`, but that does not work either!

Comment: Hint: **read** the information that is given to you. But in order to be more helpful, I added some more examples showing you how you use (still very basic) regular expressions to match more than one line.